# wicked_pdf header and footer no rendered

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am using wicked_pdf in my sinatra application. When i try to add a header or footer it is not shown in the pdf. Only the body element is working. Why the header and footer are not applied?

Here the very simple code example:

```rb
  get '/api/v1/admin/fcb/pdf/schedules/:id' do
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string("<!DOCTYPE html><p>body<p>", header: {content: "<!DOCTYPE html><h1>header</h1>"})
  end
```

This results in this PDF:
[image: pdf which only shows body]

Versions:
wicked_pdf 2.1.0
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6

Running on Debian based docker image ruby:2.6-slim

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure it out, why it did not work as expected. So I ended up in taking care of the header and footer my self. I calculated the body length in my code and added footer and header when needed.